# Nagios Issue - gwmi : The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, wmi, nagios

I'm struggling with a problem regarding the RPC server being unavailable specifically for a Nagios script written in PowerShell.

When the script is run locally, it runs perfectly and as expected. When it is called via the NRPE agent and run by the nscp service, it fails with this error:

```
gwmi : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_win_uptime.ps1:30 char:8
+ $wmi = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $ServerName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands
.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

The guts of the script (or relevant parts) are this:

```
$wmi = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $ServerName
$LBTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)
[TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)
```

No firewall is running and for testing purposes, all ports are open to the server.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Are you using the FQDN for $servername? And the NRPE agent rus with high privileges ( run as administrator) ?

Comment: Hi C.B., thanks for your comments. In this case it is a standalone server not on the domain. If I call the script using IP address, hostname or an alias which I've referenced in the Nagios hosts file, they all work for other scripts - just not those involving WMI.

As far as running NRPE as administrator, can you elaborate? it's running as local service and other scripts dependent upon admin rights run as expected already. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

RPC Server Unavailable is almost always not having enabled the right settings in Windows firewall.  See this very old topic I got written for MSDN while on the WMI team to document the issue.

[Connecting thru Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but the Windows Firewall is disabled. Any other ideas?

Comment: It may not be disabled for your type of connection.  You can also check dcomconfig [See the second topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393266(v=vs.85).aspx), but that usually shows as a E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005).  The other thing to check is the authentication settings (use -Impersonation Impersonate -Authentication PacketPrivacy), but this normally shows as WMI_ACCESSDENIED (0x80040005).

Answer (score 0):

Get-wmiobject -computer is very finicky.  This works for me:

```
$c = get-credential
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName comp001 -Credential $c
```

But other forms give the "Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)" error:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -ComputerName comp001 -Credential $c 
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName comp001 # running as same domain user as creds
```

So it looks like -Class and -Credential are mandatory.

Sometimes only something like this works:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName comp001 -Credential "dom\js" -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the problem alike but via CMD using tasklist to view remote processes. The answer is related to firework config. Convert this to a PowerShell command and it will solve your problem.

`netsh advfirework firework set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes`